# Referring to letters of the alphabet

Tags: nouns, reading-aloud, letters-of-the-alphabet

In Italian, letters can be referred to using their noun. For example, when speaking of the letter M, I could say *La lettera emme è l'undicesima lettera dell'alfabeto italiano.* (that is, "M is the 11th letter of the Italian alphabet"), or simply *Emme è l'undicesima lettera dell'alfabeto italiano*.

What is the equivalent way to refer to a letter in English?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

English doesn't name letters that way. In writing, you just use the letter itself, generally capitalized and often with quote marks around it. For example:

> Some words that begin with 'M' are *marriage*, *money*, and *military*.

That said, each letter *does* have a characteristic way to say it, such as when you're reciting the alphabet.

A - *ay*
B - *bee*
C - *see*
D - *dee*
E - *ee*
F - *eff*
G - *gee* (with a soft *g* like in *age*)
H - *aitch*
I - *eye*
J - *jay*
K - *kay*
L - *ell*
M - *em*
N - *en*
O - *oh*
P - *pee*
Q - *cue*
R - *are*
S - *ess*
T - *tee*
U - *you*
V - *vee*
W - *double you*
X - *ex*
Y - *why*
Z - *zee* or *zed*

Mostly, these pronunciations are not written down, though you can use them to emphasize a sound rather than the symbol used to write it. For example:

> Some words that begin with an 'em' sound are *marriage*, *money*, and *military*.

Comment: +1. But Bernard Shaw (who as you probably know wrote a good deal about language) actually *did* refer to the letters by their names: "A very vile jingle of esses", "This man takes more trouble to drop his aitches than ever his father did to pick them up. It's a mark of caste." This avoids the perennial problem of whether to write *Ms*, *M's*, *ms* or *m's*, and I think it's more readable and typographically more attractive.

Comment: *Zee* is American. *Haitch* is Irish (and, in Northern Ireland, the *haitch/aitch* distinction serves as a shibboleth between the Catholic and Protestant communities).

Comment: Some letters are more commonly known by written names such as [ess](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ess) for S, but others are not; in part this is because S-shaped things are common but M-shaped things less so.

Comment: G could be 'jee' rather than 'gee', assuming no-one's going to think a 'j' initial letter to be confused with 'yee' in English.

Answer (score 5):

Letters in English are simply referred to as their symbols.
However they are typically written in single or double quotes. They are also capitalized.

> 'A' is the first letter of the alphabet.

Or

> The first letter of the alphabet is "A".