# What are the English names of letters?

Tags: names, letters-of-the-alphabet

All languages which I know other than English have names for letters which can be written as words. Does English have them, and what are they? I haven't seen them anywhere, but they are not something used often because just the letters can be used in their stead.

My Idea is that the letters could be these (written with their names as words):
A, Be, Ce, De, E, Ef, Ge, Hach, I, Jay, Ka, El, Em, En, O, Pe, Qu, Er, Es, Te, U, Ve, Double U, Ex, Wy, Zed

Comment: Wikipedia: [English alphabet § Letter names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet#Letter_names)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/414/referring-to-letters-of-the-alphabet/416#416

Comment: I'm not impressed by that Wikipedia page. It specifically mentions *Plurals of vowel names also take -es (i.e., **aes, ees, ies, oes, ues**), but these are rare.* So rare, in fact, that I doubt I've *ever* seen *any* of them (and without a clear-cut context, I wouldn't understand them). But I often use and encounter ***a's, e's, i's, o's, u's*** - none of which are mentioned on that page.

Comment: I remember being intrigued to learn that the scientific instruments known as cyclotrons are built around a pair of semicircular hollow magnets, called 'dees', from their shape.

Comment: I don't like the wikipedia page either. 'a' …is that as in hat or in bate? 'cee' …is that kee or see? Not very well-written at all.

Comment: Letters are usually referred to by using the letter itself in writing, but each does have a pronunciation.  M is pronounced "em".  It would be quite unusual to use a letter's pronunciation as a word in writing. I suggest you don't do this.  There may be some exceptions like the words "aitch" and "zed", but even those are quite rare.

Comment: Most European languages using the Latin alphabet don't have names for letters, with few exceptions, e.g. "Jota" 'Spanish J, "Eszett" (ẞ in German).

Comment: Which languages do you know?  I'm aware that Greek has names for the letters. All the other languages of which I am aware don't generally have words like "Alpha, Beta..."

Comment: @JamesK I know Czech, Spanish and Hebrew. Hebrew letters have well-known names. Letters in Spanish have names which I learnt at school but haven't used much otherwise. Letters in Czech have names which are by default not declinable (“á”, “bé”), but there are longer forms which are declinable and used in morphology: “áčko”, “béčko”…; “béčkový” – related to B (like B-tier or other use cases).

Comment: English is the same as Czech and Spanish.  There are names "A Bee Cee Dee Ee Ef"  But they aren't used much

Comment: @JamesK No. In Czech, the long letter names are used often. They can be declined, which is that they have different forms for different roles in grammar, which makes them useful more than the short names or just the letters.

Comment: Yes, as in English, (although English doesn't have a case system)  You can form plurals (so different forms for different roles in English grammar):  "He wrote three aitches on the board."  English has names in the same way that Czech does.

Answer (score 1):

English letters certainly do have names, that is, commonly accepted ways of referring to them as letters. Usually we just write the letter, possibly in quotes, and rely on the reader to know how to pronounce it.

There is no standard spelling for these names. As an American I pronounce them a (long a), bee, see, dee, ee (long e), ef, gee, aitch, eye, jay, kay, el, em, en, oh, pea, queue, are, es, tee, you, vee, double-you, ex, why, and zee.

Brits pronounce the last letter "zed". Americans call it "zee". That's the only difference I know of.

Comment: "haitch" is heard in some British and Hiberno English dialects.

Comment: @TimR Good point, yes, I forgot about that.